# How do I count all of the co-occurring elements in a document line using Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have document with a bunch of phrases separated by a comma:

```
love, new, truck, present
environment, save, trying, stop, destroying
great, environment, save, money, animals, zoo, daughter, fun
impressive, loved, speech, inspiration
Happy Birthday, brother, years, old
save, money, stop, spending
new, haircut, love, check it out
```

Now I want to use Spark to count the number of co-occurring elements. Thus, I want to see

```
{
  (love, new): 2, 
  (new, truck): 1, 
  (love, truck): 1, 
  (truck, present): 1, 
  (new, present): 1,
  (love, present): 1, 
  (great, environment): 1, 
  (environment, save): 2,
  (environment, trying): 1, 
  .... 
  (love, check it out): 1
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I currently have created the RDD of the document (i'm calling it `phrase_list_RDD`) and I understand I can use a `phrase_list_RDD.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(","))` to parse the line into elements, but I'm having trouble coming up with the last part to solve my problem. If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

After splitting (and I've added trimming to get rid of spaces), you can use `List.combinations(2)` to get all combinations of two words. Passed into `flatMap`, this will result with an `RDD[List[String]]` where each record is a list of size 2.

From there on - it's a simple "word count":

```
val result: RDD[(List[String], Int)] = phrase_list_RDD
  .map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).toList) // convert records to List[String]
  .flatMap(_.combinations(2))  // take all combinations of two words
  .map((_, 1))                 // prepare for reducing - starting with 1 for each combination
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)          // reduce

// result:
// ... 
// (List(environment, daughter),1)
// (List(save, daughter),1)
// (List(money, stop),1)
// (List(great, environment),1)
// (List(save, stop),2)
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you get lines of text out of the dataframe you can split them and count the occurrences as shown below:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

object CoOccurrence {

  val text = Seq("love, new, truck, present", "environment, save, trying, stop, destroying", "great, environment, save, money, animals, zoo, daughter, fun", "impressive, loved, speech, inspiration", "Happy Birthday, brother, years, old", "save, money, stop, spending", "new, haircut, love, check it out")

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val cooc = mutable.Map.empty[(String, String), Int]

    text.foreach { line =>
      val words = line.split(",").map(_.trim).sorted
      val n = words.length
      for {
        i <- 0 until n-1
        j <- (i + 1) until n
      } {
        val currentCount = cooc.getOrElseUpdate((words(i), words(j)), 0)
        cooc((words(i), words(j))) = currentCount + 1
      }
    }

    println(cooc)

  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I assumed they were more interested in the algorithm - but Spark provides high level constructs that simplify the solution and allow it to scale. I can delete my solution if that's the recommended behavior on SO.

Comment: The resulting co-occurrence map will not scale in this solution. Also, it cannot be translated as written to Spark to run at scale: "getOrElseUpdate" is not an operation that you can perform inside of an RDD transformation.